# vimeo video hides behind header when resizing

Tags: video, iframe, responsive, vimeo

I have a responsive webpage design. I can't tell what is wrong. 
This is a provisory link to the unfinished site you can visit:
http://chromproduccions.com/web2/index.html

this is my css for the Vimeo embedded video:

```
.video-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.video-wrapper iframe, .video-wrapper object, .video-wrapper embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I have @media queries applied to the video.wrapper adding some padding, but it makes no sense because the video as you can see is responsive and that seems not to be the problem.
Any ideas, solutions and suggestions? I'll truly appreciate it.
cheers.

Comment: Well, finally, i solved it! I just needed to add a div class to all the content, and nothing else. i didn't know a div class that wasn't called in the css file could make such a difference. :D